Lattice gauge theories and commuting-operator Hamiltonians
Since the Hamiltonian of the toric code is made of mutually commuting terms that are therefore local conserved quantities, it must be naturally linked to lattice gauge theories.
What is in general the link between a Hamiltonian made of mutually commuting local terms and a corresponding lattice gauge theory, if the latter exists?
